# How to add/activate loading spinner near tab name(title) when I make an api call in angular/Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to figure out a way to show loading spinner near tab name as shown in the image below whenever I make a api call in angualrJS/javascript.

[image]

Normally whenever we refresh the page it is activated , but want to know if we could activate it using javascript or not ?

Comment: which UI frame you are using? bootstrap, materialize etc?

Comment: I am using bootstrap ..

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar using bootstrap and [font awesome icons](http://fontawesome.io/)

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="active">
     <a showtab="" href="#myTab" data-toggle="tab">
       <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spinner" data-ng-if="isLoadingData"></i>
        My Tab 
      </a>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Above, showtab is an angular directive for tabs and isLoadingData is a flag that I said before making the API call in angular and unset it on a response from API as below:

```
$scope.isLoadingData = true;
myPromiseGetObj.then(function(data){            
    $scope.listOfClosedKits = data.data.data;
    $scope.isLoadingData = false;
    callback(data.data);
});
```

myPromisePostObj is my $http get object.

Please let me know if you are stuck somewhere :)

EDITED:
To my knowledge, I dont think it could be done, instead you can use your own custom logic to show loading icons when you make API calls.

Comment: Its fine .. but when you refresh a tab near title of the page a spinner appears that is what I want to get control of ..